# Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager No XML encryptor configured. may be persisted to storage in unencrypted form LINUX

Tags: linux, .net-core

Currently having an issue with OAuth 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager No XML encryptor configured. may be persisted to storage in unencrypted form

Core 2.0
running on linux. No idea where to start

Any idea where to start looking/investigating

Comment: We never got to the bottom of this, we rolled forward with a planned release. Must of refreshed tokens and started to work again